# Cannot add for-each inside do-until in Azure Logic App

Tags: .net, azure, azure-logic-apps

I need to navigate through the data retrieve from the "GetOrdersByFilters" HTTP-Swagger connector. But unable to add for-each loop for loop through the data ("Add a for each" button is disabled in the menu).

This "GetOrdersByFilters" connector is in inside of a do-until loop(PaginationLoop).

Is there any way of adding a for-each loop?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems by design. Better option will be "GetOrdersByFilter" a child workflow and call it in do-while.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information you provided. I created a new Request/Response connector(New Workflow) and added that for-each loop inside that process and called this child workflow from parent workflow(from "PaginationLoop")